# Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function - Karma Jasmine Error in Angular V16

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

When I try to run tests in Angular V16, I get the following error.

> An error was thrown in afterAll   Uncaught TypeError:
> **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function   TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function
> at Object.9023 (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/test.ts:24:25)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at **webpack_exec** (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js:7908:48)
> at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js:7909:54
> at Function.**webpack_require**.O (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/runtime/chunk
> loaded:23:1)
> at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js:7910:56
> at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/runtime/jsonp
> chunk loading:34:1) Chrome 117.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 0
> ERROR (0.019 secs / 0 secs)

test.ts Configuration is as follows:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    <T>(id: string): T;
    keys(): string[];
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Please can someone give me a solution for this issue?